# Django can't show images on page

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I'm desperatly trying to load some images to and from my database with the help of Django.
Loading seems to work, but getting them back from the database and showing them on a webpage doesn't seem to work.

Here some info:

Environment:

myproject
|_forpix(my app)
|_myproject
|_media
  |_images
    |_mimicry3.png

I have a base.html wich includes a contentblock "allimages.html":

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<div id="imagelist">
    {% for image in images %}
    <p><img src="{{MEDIA_ROOT}}{{image.picture.url}}" />{{ image }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

This gives me the following result:
[image]

And if I click on one of the images i get:[image]

In my settings.py I've set the following:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/'),)
```

Now i really don't know how to fix this.
Can anybody provide me with some help (not the django tutorial, I've been there, tried that)

Do I have to add something in the urls.py especially for the media file? Or is it something else?

If i need to provide extra info, just ask.

Comment: did you have added `{% load staticfiles %}`  at top level of your template?

Comment: @Kasra Tried to add it, but didn't change a thing.

Comment: use `{{ STATIC_URL }}` instead of `{{MEDIA_ROOT}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^media/$` is a very wrong regex for media files.  You should delete the `$` ([end-of-the-string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)) sign from this regex.

Usually for development environments I use this snippet in the `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Also remove the useless `{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}` part from your template code. It should be:

```
<img src="{{ image.picture.url }}" />
```

Comment: @ catavaran I removed the media regex in the urls.py and added `+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` to it, but this gave me a NameError saying `name 'static' is not defined`

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. But it seemed to work, Could you please explain what just changed?

Comment: `$` is the `end-of-the-string` special char.  So the only string that matches the `^media/$` regex is `"media/"`.  All other media urls do not match with this regex.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Comment: Well I actually hoped you could explain something about the static(...) -line. I have basic knowledge of regex ( but seems to make those stupid mistakes all the time)

Comment: Serving media files with the `static()` helper is described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development

Answer (score 0):

In adition the line that you have to add is..

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

But it has to be in the urls.py of your project folder. not in the urls.py of your App folder. I knew it by mistake.